# how to query all account and account relate address in one soql?

Tags: soql

I am freshman in salesforce dev. but, today, i am facing a little issue. i want query all account address record and insert to new object.

i have following query:

for account: `SELECT Name FROM Account`

for address: `SELECT Account_vod__c, Name, Address_line_2_vod__c FROM Address_vod__c`

but, i don't know that how to join two sqls in one?

if you konw it, please tell me that how to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: Is there a relationship between the `Account` object and the `Address_vod__c` object? If so, what is the name of that field?

Comment: Account_vod__c in address object and this is account id. when i create new address, account_vod__c need to look up  account object.

Comment: @MarkPond if address and account no relationship, how to write the soql?

Comment: Is the type of the `Account_vod__c` field a Lookup or Master-Detail or just Text?

Comment: Account_vod__c Data type is Master-Detail(Account)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are performing here is a relationship query. The documentation about relationship queries can be found here: [Force.com SOQL and SOSL Reference: Relationship Queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) I would highly suggest reading the documentation to get a better understanding of the syntax to perform this type of query and how to work with the results.

Each `Account` will have a `List<Address_vod__c>` children under it which you can access using the relationship syntax.

Your query for an `Account` with it's child `Address_vod__c` records will likely look like this:

```
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id
                            , Name
                            , (SELECT Id
                                    , Account_vod__c
                                    , Name
                                    , Address_line_2_vod__c 
                                    FROM Address_vod__r)
                            FROM Account
                            LIMIT 10];

// iterate over the Accounts
for (Account a : accounts) {
    system.debug('Account: ' + a);

    // iterate over the Address_vod__c records under the Account 
    // using the relationship syntax
    for (Address_vod__c addressVOD : a.Address_vod__r) {
        system.debug('Address VOD: ' + addressVOD);

    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @MarkPond. i will read that document. Many Many thanks.